# Unable to execute maven generated jar file using java -jar 

Tags: java, maven

Hi I am using maven2 to build my project. I am able to generate the jar file using maven build with the command `mvn clean install`.

I have added this plugin to my pom.xml for manifest file to make the class path entry and main class to execute:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
       <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
               <mainClass>com.test.TestExample</mainClass>

            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>     
      </plugin>
```

When I build the project, and extracted the jar file, its generated manifest.mf file and added the main class entry as : `Main-Class: com.test.TestExample`  and added the jar files to the Class-Path:mail-1.4.jar. But when I am tryign execute the jar file using command `java -jar  TestJar.jar` I am getting the exception :

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.mail.MessagingException
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Any pointer to solve this is very helpful..

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Are you sure? Works as-is for me. You're unzipping the jar file and checking for the manifest? The plugin is in the builds/plugins element?

Comment: yes Dave, I have edited my question. Please have a look.

Comment: I have added the dependency in the pom.xml for mail.jar and its in my local path `D:\jars\mail.jar`, I am running through the eclipse, and added the entry into build path for mail.jar using the local path, now i am trying to run through the jar file, its unable to find the mail.jar. How can make the mail.jar file availabe to the jar which i am trying to execute?

Comment: By putting it on the classpath specified in the manifest file.

Comment: I have a local folder called lib, in which i have all the jars like mail.jar. Can i use that reference to make the mail.jar available?

Answer (score 1):

What you want is to indicate the location of the dependencies to the executable jar.  You could try updating your plugin configuration as follows:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
   <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
           <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
           <mainClass>com.test.TestExample</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>     
  </plugin>
```

Then ensure that the lib folder containing your dependencies are present at the same level as your executable jar.

Comment: Hi Raghuram,  i have a classpath `D:/eclipseWS/TestProj/src/main/resources/lib/xstream-1.2.2.jar"/`, and i mentioned <addClasspath>true</addClasspath> 
        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>, but i am unable to find the jar files from the lib folder.. thanks for your time

Comment: You had commented that you had a local folder called `lib` where you had all these jars. My answer was in response to that.  The above snippet will not put any jars anywhere